# Using perspective library with Corona SDK

Tags: coronasdk

I'm trying to use the [Perspective Virtual Camera](https://gist.github.com/GymbylCoding/8675733) library, to create a game, where the player can move, the library seems to be pretty famous as a see many people referring to it, but i did not found any tutorials on how to use it. The "Camera" is working, and the man player is being followed around, but thats it.

[image: The Layers added to the camera]

Basically i want the Background Sky to always stay in the screen. And the mountains and threes to move. How could i do that? **Is this the right tool to do the job**?

This is the code to add then to the Camera:

```
camera:add(background, 8, false) -- SKY
camera:add(montanhas, 7, false) -- Mountains
camera:add(arvores, 6, false) -- Trees
camera:add(floor,5, false) 
camera:add(hero, 1, true) - hero
```

The grey circles on the bottom of the image, are my HUD, i'm not adding them to the camera ( just to scene ), so they just stay in the correct position.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to use your plugin, but it might be easier to not use it.  Just create different groups with the `display.newGroup()` api.  You would basically have one group for the foreground, and one group for the background.

You might want to try this. Instead of inserting the background into the groups set by that program, use the `object:toBack()` API.